# DFS Complexity with two recursive calls to each child in binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, time-complexity, depth-first-search

So let's say the problem is calculating the number of paths in a binary tree whose sum is equal to some target.

One simple way to do this is to recursively call DFS twice for each child, once for using child node for a path that started somewhere before it and once to start searching for path starting at child node.

Time complexity of this approach would be O(4^k), where *k* is the height of the tree, but what would be the complexity in respect to the number of nodes *n* in the tree?

I know that regular DFS has O(n) time complexity since it visits each tree node only once, but this approach would visit node at level *m* 2^m times if I'm not mistaken.

Here is my code for the problem in python.

```
def cnt_paths(root, target):
    return dfs(root, target, 0, set())


def dfs(node, target, current_sum, visited):
    cnt = 0
    if current_sum + node.val == target:
        cnt += 1

    if node.left:
        cnt += dfs(node.left, target, current_sum + node.val, visited)  # include this node
        if node.left not in visited:
            cnt += dfs(node.left, target, 0, visited)  # start from scratch on next node
            visited.add(node.left)

    if node.right:
        cnt += dfs(node.right, target, current_sum + node.val, visited)
        if node.right not in visited:
            cnt += dfs(node.right, target, 0, visited)
            visited.add(node.right)

    return cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking any deeper into your code, if indeed you already know that its time complexity is *O(4<sup>k</sup>)* for tree height *k*, then we can find the complexity for the number of nodes too.

A binary tree of height *k* has *n = O(2^k)* nodes, Thus,

*O(4<sup>k</sup>) = O(4<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>) = O(2<sup>2 * log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>) = O((2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>)<sup>2</sup>)= O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity you list is not correct. If the depth of a node is *d*, then that node is used together with *d* different starting points of the sum (the root, the root's child, ... the node's parent, or the node itself). In other words, the expression `current_sum + node.val` is evaluated *d* times for a particular `node` (but with varying `current_sum` values).

This means in total you have SUM[depth(node)] of such operations. In a perfect binary tree, this sum is:

1 + 2*2 + 3*4 + 4*8 + ... + 2<sup>-1</sup>

where  is the height of the tree. This sum is smaller than

∑<sub><sub>=1..</sub></sub>2<sup>-1</sup>

which equals (2-1), which is

O(2)

The number of nodes  in a perfect binary tree of height  is =2, so the number of operations, rewritten in terms of  is:

O(log())